# rsync privilages to delete source and destination files

Tags: bash, shell, backup

I am using rsync in my bash script to backup a websites 'public_html' folder to a local destination folder on my computer.

Here is my rsync code:

```
if  rsync -zavx -e 'ssh -p22' \
        --numeric-ids \
        --delete -r \
        --link-dest=../"$yesterday" "$site_source" "$site_dest";
then        
    ...
else
    ...
fi
```

What I am confused by, is what privileges rsync has to delete files. I want to ensure that its not possible for any 'source' files to be deleted by the script and limit any local deletion to a single folder area.

I've been reading over the docs and I see `--exclude` and `--filter`, but these appear to be only able to be used to exclude and filter which files are synced.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, or potentially explain what privileges rsync has to 'source' files, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from `man rsync`:

```
--delete                delete extraneous files from dest dirs
```

rsync will not delete source files.

Comment: Just adding a note here : option `--remove-source-files` will remove the source files after they are sent to the destination